# How to exclude files from rake assets:precompile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, asset-pipeline

There is an enormous JS library that is part of my app, as well as a surfeit of images.  The JS library never changes and the images almost never do.

Is there a way to exclude them from `rake assets:precompile`?

Would it be a bad idea to just move them to public/ ?